# Neo4j auto index new user creation

Tags: neo4j

Good evening,

I'm a bit confused here and curious on how to handle this.

I'm creating a new user in Neo4j 3.0 using neo4j-php-client. What I'm wondering is how I go about auto-increment on the user_id.

```
$client->run("CREATE (n:User:Artist) SET n += {infos}", ['infos' => ['id' => $id, 'first_name' => $fname, 'last_name' => $lname, 'slug' => $slug, 'born' => $born, 'bio' => $bio, 'password' => $pass, 'email' => $email, 'ip' => $ip, 'date_created' => $date_created, 'date_modified' => $last_updated, 'last_login' => $last_login, 'verified' => $verified, 'notified' => $notified]]);
```

My current data was imported from MySQL database and now I'm trying to create new users through Neo4j. Perhaps I am missing something here.

Thanks,
Grant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in facility for auto-incrementing properties. However, you can substitute for it, though it is going to get substantially slower as your data set grows:

```
MATCH (n:User:Artist)
WITH COALESCE(MAX(n.user_id) + 1, 1) AS new_user_id
CREATE (n:User:Artist) 
SET n.user_id = new_user_id
SET n += {infos}
```

If your data set is large, you can work around this by keeping some kind of `:Status` node around to track these properties for you, but you will have to manually enforce this auto-increment in your queries.

Comment: Does this make any sense or should I be doing this differently?
And it does seem to do some type of AI as each node has <id>:
which appears to be assigned by Neo4j.

Comment: Also can you clarify slower, I assume you just mean on creation. I can't see this causing read side to be slower.

Comment: It will only be slower on write, you are correct, because it has to perform the `MAX` aggregation each time it assigns a new `user_id`. If you have another unique property or combination of properties that will allow you to identify the node, you don't need a separate ID property. Also, the internal ID isn't a property, it's just a key used by the kernel to tie together all the other identifiers and allow for quick set ops, you shouldn't ever rely on it.

Comment: Great, that is sufficient for me to keep going!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative you might consider is using a generated uuid in place of a auto-incremented sequence identifier.

Mathematically a uuid should be globally unique, and depending on the type and implementation library, extremely rare for there to be a collision.

APOC Procedures offers a uuid generation function, and you can find uuid generators for whatever server side language you're using that's doing the querying.